# Reading Multiple data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqldatareader

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Ontrip _ontrip = new Ontrip(_FNAME);

        string _query2 = "select CContactno from CustomerTbl where CUsername = @USERNAME";
        string _query3 = "select Price from TransactionTypeTble T join PendingTransTbl P ON P.TransType = T.TransType ";
        string _query4 = "select VehicleDescription from DriverTbl D join VehicleSpecTbl V ON D.VehicleType = V.VehicleType";


        SqlConnection _sqlcnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MELIODAS;Initial Catalog=WeGo;Integrated Security=True");
        _sqlcnn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader _reader = null;
            SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CFName+' '+CLName from CustomerTbl where CUsername=@USERNAME", _sqlcnn);

            SqlParameter _param = new SqlParameter();
            _param.ParameterName = "@USERNAME";
            _param.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            _cmd.Parameters.Add(_param);

            _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();         //for displaying users name in the label
            while (_reader.Read())
            {
                _ontrip._txtboxUsername.Text = _reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        using (SqlCommand _sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(_query2, _sqlcnn))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader _reader = null;

                SqlParameter _param = new SqlParameter();
                _param.ParameterName = "@USERNAME";
                _param.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                _sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(_param);

                _reader = _sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();         //for displaying users name in the label
                while (_reader.Read())
                {
                    _ontrip._txtboxContact.Text = _reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is their a way for me to read the query and display the output, when i run this code their is an error saying that their is already an open data reader associated with the command. I should be displaying multiple data in a textbox

Comment: Which line of code gives the error? You are setting the text property of text box in the while loop so you will get the last value of the reader at the end of the loop. You want to display all the values if reader in textbox comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

try Call Close when done reading.

_reader.Close();

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Ontrip _ontrip = new Ontrip(_FNAME);

        string _query2 = "select CContactno from CustomerTbl where CUsername = @USERNAME";
        string _query3 = "select Price from TransactionTypeTble T join PendingTransTbl P ON P.TransType = T.TransType ";
        string _query4 = "select VehicleDescription from DriverTbl D join VehicleSpecTbl V ON D.VehicleType = V.VehicleType";


        SqlConnection _sqlcnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MELIODAS;Initial Catalog=WeGo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True ");
        _sqlcnn.Open();
```

I added MultipleActiveResultSet or MARS